# List assigned to Json deserialize is null

Tags: c#, json, null, deserialization

Since my last question was marked as duplicate and i didn't find an answer in recommended link i'm asking my question again.

I want to deserialize some JSON data and pass it to view in my ASP.NET MVC 5 app.

My model:

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public string Seat { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdAt { get; set; }

}
```

I've read that to deserialize JSON data to list of object i have to make "root" class which is here:

```
public class OrderRootModel
{
    public List<OrderModel> OrderList { get; set; }

}
```

Here is a method that gets JSON data in ApiModel class and assignsit to list. **This method is probably a problem since it is returning null** :

```
//ApiModel class
    public OrderRootModel GetOrderData()
        {

            string url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Orders";

            OrderRootModel model = new OrderRootModel();
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRootModel>(getParseIdData(url));
            return model;
        }
```

Here is a method that gets JSON string:

```
public string getParseIdData(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", id);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", key);
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(errorText);
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Here is getParseIdData() response:

```
{"results":[{"Seat":"5","createdAt":"2015-11-29T18:50:15.320Z","objectId":"BsDSolYPsT","updatedAt":"2015-11-29T19:40:55.020Z"},{"Seat":"6","createdAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:36.892Z","objectId":"kQJ0R5TUvw","updatedAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:36.892Z"},{"Seat":"7","createdAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:40.261Z","objectId":"sVtdj3aipb","updatedAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:40.261Z"},{"Seat":"8","createdAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:43.082Z","objectId":"7oH2ySrDFH","updatedAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:43.082Z"}]}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ApiModel model = new ApiModel();

            return View(model.GetOrderData()) ;
        }
```

So probably i've made a mistake somewhere in GetOrderData() method since it returns null. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be named `OrderList`, it should be named `results`. Your `OrderModel` class is also missing the `updatedAt` field.

Comment: It works now. Holy moly that was a stupid mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC5 JSON list NullReference exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072703/mvc5-json-list-nullreference-exception)

Comment: @Kesto here is a really good site that you can use in regards to creating C# Classes from Json strings I use this all the time http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code this is what would the C# Class should look like when converting your JSON to a C# Class

```
{
    "results":[
      {"Seat":"5","createdAt":"2015-11-29T18:50:15.320Z","objectId":"BsDSolYPsT","updatedAt":"2015-11-29T19:40:55.020Z"},
      {"Seat":"6","createdAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:36.892Z","objectId":"kQJ0R5TUvw","updatedAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:36.892Z"},
      {"Seat":"7","createdAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:40.261Z","objectId":"sVtdj3aipb","updatedAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:40.261Z"},
      {"Seat":"8","createdAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:43.082Z","objectId":"7oH2ySrDFH","updatedAt":"2015-12-02T22:31:43.082Z"}
      ]
}

public class Result
{
    public string Seat { get; set; }
    public string createdAt { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public string updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```